# How to receive meeting requests through amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, imap, mime, amazon-ses

I am looking for a way to receive all of my company emails and locate those that contain meeting requests, then extract and store following meeting information in a dynamoDB

Creator
Start
End
Location
Attendees

Is this possible and if so is amazon SES the correct route? Can currently receive emails through SES and store in a S3 bucket, but the email is in MIME formate and not all of the meeting information is readily available.
Trying to avoid having to build fancy string passing functions to extract this information if possible.

Comment: If you are successfully receiving your emails via this method, then Yes, it is possible but you would have to write the code yourself, such as in an AWS Lambda function triggered by receiving the email. Do you have a question beyond "is this possible"?

Comment: So far as I can see the meeting information isn't always readily available in the MIME, specifically attendees for meeting requests sent from outlook. This is why I was unsure whether SES is the correct tool. I am looking for a a library or code snippet that I can write in a lambda function to robustly extract this meeting information.